# $(element).outerWidth(true) reports differently based on theme?

Tags: jquery, css, width

I have a jQuery script, this sets an element's width to 50% via the normal CSS width attribute.

If I then output the `outerWidth(true)` of that element to get the exact pixel value, it sometimes does not correspond to `$(window).width()/2` - this is based on the theme that the site has. Unfortunately I cannot bring a demo for this behavior online.

Is there any specific CSS attribute that might cause such a difference?

The problem is that the `outerWidth()` is reporting for example, `564px`, but when I check in Safari inspector, it says `580`. So the return of that function is incorrect and I'd like to be able to know what is the cause.

Demo:

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/this/

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/that/

The content (gray area when you click on the red tab) is supposed to be hidden on load via a negative margin, but due to the (incorrect?) return of jquery, it is not in one of these themes (showing slightly).

console.log calls are :

```
        console.log('window width / 2 = ' + $(window).width()/2);
        console.log('doc width /2  = ' + $(document).width()/2);

        console.log('width = ' + defaults.boxWidth);
        console.log('width = ' + $slider.css('width'));
        console.log('width = ' + $slider.width());
        console.log('width = ' + $slider.outerWidth());
        console.log('width = ' + $slider.outerWidth(true));
```

Comment: What exactly are you talking about when you say _"theme"_?  Yes, you can and should put a demo online... use jsFiddle.net

Comment: @Sparky672 - Different HTML based layouts; a completely different site design, different CSS, etc.. (but not different for the element).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`.outerWidth([includeMargin])`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) - Returns the width of the element, along with left and right padding, border, and (optionally) margin in pixels.

---

Setting the `[includeMargin]` option to `true` adds the margins to this number:

[`.outerWidth(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) - Returns the width of the element, along with left and right padding, border, **and margin**, in pixels.

---

[`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) - Returns a *unit-less* pixel value **not including** left and right padding, border, or margin.

As per jQuery docs, the **only** difference between `.width()` and `.css(width)` is that the latter includes the units ('px') where `width()` simply returns the number (without the 'px').

**So if, by definition, `width()` does not include margins, padding, and borders, then neither can `css(width)`**

---

> I have a jQuery script, this sets an element's width to 50% via the
>   normal CSS width attribute.

This is setting the element itself (not including margin, padding or borders) to 50% of it's container.  If the window is the container, then the element's width will be 50% of that.

**Example:**  With a window of 1160 pixels wide, your script will create an element at 50% of 1160, or 580 pixels wide (not including margin, padding or borders).

> If I then output the `outerWidth(true)` of that element to get the exact
>   pixel value, it sometimes does not correspond to `$(window).width()/2`.

When you look at the same element with `outerWidth(true)`, now you're adding margin, padding or borders to the number.

**Using my same example:**  With a window of 1160 pixels, `$(window).width()/2` will be 580. Assuming your element is also 580 pixels, `.outerWidth(true)` will add (or subtract) margins, add border and add padding to the element itself so you are not going to get 580 unless margins, padding and border are all zero.

So naturally, with a different "theme" (using your definition), the element is probably going to have a different padding, border and margins.  I cannot say for sure since I cannot see any of your code.

Simply use `.width()` in place of `.outerWidth(true)` to keep things consistent across all of your themes.

---

**EDIT:**

In the Safari console, I'm seeing a margin on the `body` causing what you describe.  Inside your `consolidated-screen-2.css` sheet you have a 20 pixel left margin.

**You must take this body margin into account when you do your calculations.**

Since your JavaScript does not dynamically update and this is not in a jsFiddle, I cannot test it any further.  When I set the margin to 0 in the DOM, I cannot invoke the JS to recalculate the numbers without reloading the page, which of course, wipes out my DOM over-ride.

One solution would be to stick with `.width()` (ignore margins) in all your calculations.

An alternate solution would seem to include setting the `body` margin to zero.

---

**EDIT 2:**

You keep saying it's reporting incorrectly, but I have a semi-opaque pixel ruler utility overlaid on my screen for the following and everything is checking out...

[This page](http://users.telenet.be/prullen/this/) in a 1228 pixel wide window.  Ruler verifies this.

`console.log('width = ' + $slider.outerWidth(true));` = 1188

1188 **plus** 40 pixels (`body` left/right margins) = 1228 (same as ruler)

Drawer is open and ruler verifies it is **exactly 614 pixels wide** (without the right border).

`console.log('width = ' + $slider.css('width'));` = 594 px;

594 **plus** 20 pixels (`body` left margin) = 614 (same as ruler)

`console.log('width = ' + $slider.width());` = 594

594 **plus** 20 pixels (`body` left margin) = 614 (same as ruler)

Comment: The elements width has been set to 50% via CSS. css width is including everything (margin/padding) so shouldn't outerwidth(true) report the same as window.width() (outerwidth on a window does not exist, of course)

Comment: Also, why would the element have a different padding, border, etc. This remains the same, something else is affecting it and I don't know what.

Comment: _why would the element have a different padding, border, etc._... because it's a different theme (and I cannot see any of your code).  What's the point of a theme if everything is exactly the same?

Comment: _"something else is affecting it and I don't know what."_  Neither do we, **and we'll never know**, until you post something we can work with.

Comment: @Wesley quote:  _"css width is including everything (margin/padding)"_  This is exactly where you are going wrong.  CSS `width` does NOT include the margin, padding or border.

Comment: The demo is now online, check original message. thanks so for for your help.

Comment: @Wesley, it's the margin on your body causing the inconsistency you're seeing.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but seems it's not so easy to fix. Is it normal that outerwidth() of an element (not the body) reports differently when that body margin is set? It's an extra margin on the body, not on the element?

Comment: You are right, I just expected 100% to be the full body size. Not with margins discounted. That's what I wanted to achieve anyway, I now solve it your way. Thanks.

Comment: @Wesley: Yes, that's the difference between `width` and `outerWidth`.  Glad you realized that and got it working.

Comment: yes, lol, you certainly sticked with me throughout this issue, most would have given up ;) Thx

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `outerWidth(true)` are supposed to be two different things. The first doesn't include the padding, border, or margin -- the second does.

If you want the `outerWidth` to be exactly half the window width, you'll have to explicitly factor those things in:

```
var $el = $('#el');
var wid = $(window).width()/2
     - parseInt($el.css('padding-left')) - parseInt($el.css('padding-right'))
     - parseInt($el.css('border-left')) - parseInt($el.css('border-right'))
     - parseInt($el.css('margin-left')) - parseInt($el.css('margin-right'))
// assumes all those things are set using pixels, not em or percent or something
$el.width(wid);
```

Comment: Neither width() or outerWidth(true) (on the element) report the same as $(window).width/2 (based on setting the width to 50%) - there's always a 10 or 20px difference.

Comment: Hard to be sure where the problem is if we can't see the page ourselves. Use a debugger like Chrome's or Firebug to inspect the CSS on the element.

Comment: The problem is that the outerWidth() is reporting for example, 564px, but when I check in safari inspector, it says 580. So the return of that function is incorrect and I'd like to be able to know what is the cause - I'd like to continue to set the width of that element via normal CSS rules, not via a calculated value. It's jquery that is simply reporting an incorrect value.

Comment: @Wesley, it's very unlikely that jQuery is reporting anything incorrectly.  We'd love to solve this for you but without a concrete working example, we're only guessing.

Comment: Just a thought: in Safari, could it be that you are capturing the width and then a moment later scroll bars show up causing the width to differ when you check it in the inspector?

Comment: I'll see if I can get a demo online somehow.. Shouldn't be caused by scrollbars though.

Comment: The demo is now online, check original message. Thanks so far for your help.